# Should I keep the microwave turntable and plastic turntable support ring in the microwave oven when using convection mode?

Tags: oven, microwave, convection

I am trying to operate a microwave convection oven for the first time. It is a GE Profile convection/microwave oven.  I am wondering if I am supposed to keep the glass microwave turntable and plastic microwave turntable support ring in the unit when I am operating in convection mode.  I know the first thing people will say is to read the owners manual, but the owners manual is extremely unclear.

[Here is a manual I found online](https://secure.img1-ag.wfcdn.com/docresources/45026/85/852318.pdf), which is for a model very similar to the one I have.

On page 8 of this manual, as well as on page 8 of the manual that came with my model,  they discussed that the metal shelves should not be in the unit when microwaving food, but they don’t mention anything about the glass turntable and plastic turntable support ring  being used in convection mode. You might ask: why don’t I just remove these two items anyway when using convection mode just to be safe? The answer is that the support ring sits on a piece of plastic, and that piece of plastic seemingly can’t be removed, so I will still have to worry about plastic in the unit while using convection mode. So is that piece of plastic that’s part of the unit safe for the convection oven?

Comment: I guess no one knows.

Comment: GE has a help line you can call and an email service you can write. They will know more about your product than anyone here as one may have noticed.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot vouch for your specific GE oven, but I've been using my combination oven with the turntable and turntable support in Microwave, Convection Bake, Convection Roast and Combination Fast Bake for the last >10 years with no ill effects.

As your oven has the same technical capabilities as mine:

> **Combination Fast Cooking**
>   Your oven also offers the option of Combination Fast Cook, using microwave energy along with convection cooking. You cook with speed and accuracy, while browning and crisping to perfection.

I'm led to believe you're safe to use the turntable in convection only mode like I do as my round shelf fits perfectly on the glass turntable, so I never asked myself the question and have just used it like that since the first time I turned on the oven.

Comment: Interesting. I don’t have a round shelf. But as you can see from the manual I linked, it is extremely unclear.

Comment: @layman Item #7 on page 8 of your manual is the square variety only? My oven (Whirlpool) came with the round one only and that's why I never asked myself the question...

Comment: That’s right! It’s a rectangle that acts as a shelf.

Comment: Well, I'm sticking to my guns.  **;-)** However, you might want to wait at least 24h so the entire planet has had a chance to have a look and other's opinions might vary from mine.  An upvote would be welcome while you wait!  **;-)**

Comment: I will definitely wait for the whole world to get in on the discussion. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Well, the whole world has had a look @layman so if my answer did help, don't forget to [accept](/help/accepted-answer).  **;-)**

Comment: I hope your answer has helped someone, especially someone with the same model as you, but unfortunately, it did not help my situation as we seem to have different models.  I would hate for someone to come across this question having my specific model, and for them to not read all posts carefully, and then believe that because your answer was accepted, that I somehow verified it.  I have not verified it and am too scared to for fear of somehow breaking the machine.

Answer (score 2):

If the plastic part is non-removable, then better leave the glass plate in place. Better some spots on glass, than grease. crumbs and other stuff dripping from the convection-cooked food jamming the mechanics and stopping the turntable permanently. In this case the glass plate acts as a protective cover. In convection mode, the inside is thermoregulated (the temperature never exceeding preset on the thermostat) so the plastic will never reach dangerous temperatures; in microwave mode it's entirely transparent to microwaves so unless it's seriously dirty, it won't heat up at all.

You may consider using a non-stick baking sheet (teflon foil) on the bottom to protect it from 'drips'. Otherwise, just keep it clean.

Comment: Are you advising from experience or inside GE knowledge? Just curious.

Comment: @Suse: Experience. I have a combo microwave/grill, and I get dripping/falling stuff from the grill grate whenever I use it; there's no reason convection oven would behave any better. (and unlike convection oven the grill is not thermoregulated).

Comment: I thought about what you said, scoured the manual ( didn't find much) and I see what you mean. I am going to try to keep the glass plate in place when using convection oven. Just will try to keep the glass plate clean!

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this question and though I am 5 months late, I can definitely weigh in here on your question. I used a microwave-convection oven (GE profile) for many years and you are correct, that the wire shelves should be removed while microwaving. However, what no one tells you, is that the round glass turntable should be removed while in convection mode. The reason is that if there is any trace of any food particle on the glass, the glass will start to turn brown and no manner of cleaning or washing will ever get it clean because it will have baked into the glass. I don't know exactly how it happens, but it does. So, I just bought a new one (why, is another story) and I am trying to be very particular about removing the glass while in convection mode and the wire shelves while in microwave mode. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your input!  What about the plastic component I described in the original post?  It is worrisome that it is seemingly unremovable, yet I don't think plastic should be in the oven.

Comment: That's interesting. Most of the plastic rings ( called turntable support rings) are removable and that could be removed as well. The small plastic piece that is connected could be covered as stated previously with metal when baking to prevent  overheating.

Comment: The plastic ring is definitely removable. But it and the turntable sit on a white piece of plastic that seems to be permanently attached to the center.

Comment: See the comment I posted below about my change of mind and keeping the glass plate in place. I think @SF has the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of my combi microwave/oven there is a very clear message that you have to leave in the plastic turn thingy and the glass or ceramic turning plate/dish has to stay in the machine while using it as an oven.

So go with your oven instructions and if no clear instructions are given you might search the actual brand and model on internet to find the actual instructions.

(And clean the dish before you use it as an oven if you are worried about burned food.)